# Pancakes and Waffles

Tags: dairy, breakfast

Is it possible to make pancakes and waffles using the rich flavor of coffee creamer or half-and-half? I want to make pancakes and waffles using out of the box dairy ingredients.

Comment: Can you add some details to your question, to explain better what you're looking to do?  Like, what do you mean "out of the box"?  By "creamer" do you mean non-dairy creamer?  Are you looking to substitute these into an existing recipe?

Comment: So you are basically trying to increase the fat content? Yeah, possible, but it will alter the texture. Can you elaborate a bit more on your plans, so that we can come up with a more qualified answer?

Comment: This seems like one of those things it would be quicker to try than to wait for answers to.

Comment: I just want to make pancakes and waffles using coffee creamer instead of milk.

Answer (score 2):

**Sure!**

I had some powdered milk a while ago.  Pandemic supplies.  It all went into pancakes.  A lot of bread machine recipes call for powdered milk.  It is shelf stable and handy if there are not milk drinkers in the house.

Go ahead and use your creamer or powdered milk or whatever it is.  You will need to add water to make the batter pourable.  Maybe you could use your leftover coffee.  The creamer will be happy to see its buddy.

Comment: Creamer is not powdered milk.  It's a non-dairy, carbohydrate based product.

Comment: @FuzzyChef:  very true.  Neither is coffee.  Or applesauce; applesauce makes a dynamite pancake.

Comment: Powdered orange drink, however, does not.

Comment: /Powdered orange drink, however, does not/   ...really.  <fingers goatee skeptically>.  To the kitchen, Fuzzy!  We will determine the truth soon enough!

Comment: Anyway, I know that non-dairy creamer does not work in baked goods because of a prior question on another forum.  Someone tried to make a pie with it.

Comment: @FuzzyChef - I can see how that might be true.  But in a role as flavorful liquid to thin the batter it seems like it would be ok.  Some people make pancakes with water.

Comment: @Willk I substitute half of the milk in my pancake recipe for orange juice, and it's great. Pancakes are not so finicky that liquid substitutions are likely to ruin them.

Comment: @Willk see my answer for why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have used coconut milk as well as non-dairy milk, (I think it was soya but not sure as someone else bought it,) in pancakes and those all worked out great.  You can even used plain water and oil, egg and one of the many different kinds of flour in a pinch.

You will have to experiment and the resulting pancakes may be more bread like in some cases.

Based on that I am sure your milk replacements will work.
I doubt however that you will get a creamy result, as you will have to dilute till almost milk consistency to get a working pancake batter.

I am not as familiar with making waffles but seeing the very wide range of recipes and resulting waffles I am sure it can be done. Select a recipe that uses milk or a replacement to start with and use your cream or creamer instead. Diluting if needed if pooring is part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use non-dairy coffee creamer in place of dairy products in baking.  Creamer is made from a combination of sugar, starches, oil, and thickeners.  It does not behave like, or taste like, milk.  Further, if you heat it above boiling temperature, it separates into carbohydrates and oil, resulting in a greasy mess.